# Search for people within the age range

Tags: mysql

I want to search a database for people in age range.

```
WITH age_group AS
(
SELECT 'A' num, 4 start_age, 99 end_age, 2 quantity FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'A', 0, 3, 2 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'A', 0, 99, 3 FROM dual

UNION ALL SELECT 'B', 4, 18, 2 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'B', 3, 17, 1 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'B', 4, 99, 1 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 'B', 4, 99, 3 FROM dual
)
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT
    num
    , SUM(a18) AS sum18
    , SUM(a11) AS sum11
    , SUM(quantity) AS max_quantity
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            num
            , IF(start_age <= 18 AND 18 <= end_age , quantity, 0) AS a18
            , IF(start_age <= 11 AND 11 <= end_age , quantity, 0) AS a11
            , quantity
        FROM age_group
    ) AS age_sum
GROUP BY num
) AS age
WHERE sum18 >= 5 AND sum11 >= 2
```

age_group defines the age group and the number of people allowed to enter.

Room A can accommodate 2 people aged 4 to 99, 2 people aged 0 to 3, and 3 people aged 0 to 99.

5 people aged 18 and 2 people aged 11 cannot enter Room A.

5 people aged 18 and 2 people aged 2 can enter room A.

Room B can accommodate 2 people aged 4 to 18, 1 person aged 3 to 17, 1 person aged 4 to 99, and 3 people aged 4 to 99.

5 people aged 18 and 2 people aged 11 can enter Room B.

5 people aged 18 and 1 person aged 17 can enter Room B.

1 people aged 18 and 1 person aged 2 cannot enter Room B.

That query statement is a condition for searching room A.

App-generated target age criteria ("IF (start_age <= 18 AND 18 <= end_age, quantity, 0) AS a18 ..", "sum18>= 5 AND sum11>= 2").

However, if both "18" and "11" match, they are counted at both 11 and 18 giving incorrect results.

Incorrect query result.
5 people aged 18 and 2 people aged 11 can enter Room A.

However, cannot actually enter.

Comment: What a weird set of rules

Comment: Which one is weird? English is not good, but I will try my best to explain.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to say: Room A can accommodate (2 people aged 4 to 99 and 2 people aged 0 to 3) or (3 people aged 0 to 99). That would kind of make sense, because that could be related to the sizes of bed, say, that could be provided.

Comment: The data is correct. High degree of freedom when entering data. That room can actually accommodate 7 people.

Comment: I don't get it; I'm not good at thinking in the abstract and I just can't imagine a scenario where these rules could apply

Comment: That said, I think it would be more normal to articulate that statement this way: Room A can accommodate up to 7 people, comprising a maximum of 7 people aged 4-99 and a maximum of 5 people aged 0-3

Comment: I have a partner who is not clearly set up with 3 adults and 1 infant. It is a room that can accommodate up to 4 people, but I would like to set it to 2 people aged 4-18, 1 person aged 15-18, and 1 person aged 18. (partner)

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you. Inspired by your writing.

Comment: Hope it helps. I still think a statement like `2 people aged 4 to 18, 1 person aged 3 to 17` is an unrealistic and arbitrary constraint.